# WebMatrix says MySQL Connector/NET is an old version when it is not

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am trying to access a MySql database using an ADO.NET .aspx file but I get an error. When I try to open the database in WebMatrix I get this error:

> Please ensure that the MySQL Connector/Net ADO.NET driver (version
>   6.2.3 or greater) is installed Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.DependenciesMissingException:
>   Please ensure that the MySQL Connector/Net ADO.NET driver (version
>   6.2.3 or greater) is installed    bij Microsoft.WebMatrix.DatabaseManager.MySqlDatabase.MySqlDatabaseProvider.VerifyDependencies()
>   ...
>   etc.

But I already have the latest version of this driver installed (MySQL Connector Net 6.7.4) Also, there is no other Connector installed (except for a ODBC 5.2 32bit and ODBC 5.2 64bit version).

All connectors that are available on MySQL ([here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/)) with version 6.2.5 or higher are for 32bit, but I have 64bit Windows 7 PC. I don't know if that is relevant.

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for the answer, I fixed it myself in a somewhat unusual way.

I already had a WebMatrix project with a MySQL database connection, I closed WebMatrix and then I removed the MySQL Connector Net in Windows configuration. When I restarted WebMatrix and clicked on the database connection a window came up saying I needed a driver and proposed to download it.

After that it all worked!

When I looked at software installed in Windows configuration I found: 'MySQL Connector Net 6.5.4'.